Wilcoxon signed-rank test always finding randomly generated ratios to be different from unity?
I need to test if a group of ratios from an experiment (calculated as condition1/condition2 from paired samples) is significantly different from one. All measures in the experiment are positive, real numbers, so I figure the distribution around 1 will something more log-normal so a t-test is inappropriate. My first thought was to use the Wilcoxon signed-rank test (as implemented in scipy.stats.wilcoxon). I wanted to test it with modeled data first to see if it was reasonable to do, and I don't understand the results. I'm using the code below to test it.
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import wilcoxon, ttest_1samp

n_iters = int(1e4)
n_samps = int(100)
n_sig = 0
for iter in range(n_iters):
    s0 = np.random.rand(n_samps)
    s1 = np.random.rand(n_samps)
    ratio = s0/s1
    p = wilcoxon(ratio-1, alternative='greater').pvalue
    # p = ttest_1samp(np.log(ratio), 0, alternative='greater').pvalue
    if p < 0.05:
        n_sig += 1
print(n_sig/n_iters*100)

Running this code as is, about half of the ratios are 'significant'. As n_samps (the number of samples drawn for each iteration) increases, the number of ratios that are significant increases to 100%. I had expected roughly 5% of the ratios to be significant given my chosen p threshold. If I calculate the p value as p = ttest_1samp(np.log(ratio), 0, alternative='greater').pvalue (currently commented out), I always get ~5% of the tests to be significant, regardless of the value of n_samps.
Am I misunderstanding the Wilcoxon test here? I thought it was specifically meant to be used when the underlying distribution was not normal. Note the random samples s0 and s1 are both generated using the same function, which draws from a uniform distribution on the interval [0, 1), so while the median is one, I think the distribution is more log-normal.

I am not sure what you think the Wilcoxon Signed Rank test (WSRt) tests for, but most likely it does not test for what you think it tests.
In spite of what (too) many textbooks, sites, and even python's documentation say, it is not a test of the median, but a test of the pseudomedian (the median of all possible paired averages from the sample).
While the median of your ratios should be (and is) 1, the pseudomedian is not, because of the "outliers" (i.e. ratios with very large values, due to division by a near 0 value).
Now the WSRt becomes a test of the median, iff the sample comes from a symetrical distribution. But your distribution of ratios is (very) positively skewed, so the pseudomedian is (very) different from the median.
And then, since your null is false, as you increase the sample size (and hence the power of the test), all samples will return a significant result. So what you observe is exactly as it should be.
Now if you used Mood's median test (median_test in python), I am pretty sure you will have different results, in line with your expectations, because this is truly a test of the median.
The real sad thing is how often the WSRt is presented as an alternative to a t-test, even though both tests test completely different null hypotheses (and btw, the median test also tests a different null).
Now what can you do? First it depends on your sample size. If it is similar to your simulation (100, or more), then it is large enough for the CLT to kick in, and make the sampling distribution of means "pretty close" to a normal, so that a t-test will actually give you a reasonable answer. (see this histogram
of the means of 5000 lognormal samples of size 100; it is still skewed, but "close enough". And you can run simulations to see if it is "close enough" for your specific case). If your sample size is smaller, a t-test becomes questionable. But if your sample is still of "reasonable" size ($\approx \ge 50$?), bootstraping of the mean (and the corresponding CI) may be viable. And of course the median test would also make the case you are trying to make (more than half of the ratios are >1). A t-test (or the bootstrap test of the mean) however should have higher power.

Thank you. You are exactly correct - I had always been told/read the WSRt was basically an alternative to the t-test for non-normal distributions. Very good to know this information. I appreciate the detail and links.
